# Spring Data Redis global TTL for all entities

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I need to set global TTL to each entity I have and it should be configurable in one place. 
There is an opportunity to do this via @RedisHash annotation:

```
@RedisHash(value = "persons",timeToLive = 100)
public class Person{
  ...
}
```

or I can have a field

```
 public class Person{
      @TimeToLeave
      Long ttl;
 }
```

but in this case I can't change it in one place and it's not really comfortable
to maintain it.
I have a property in applicaiton.properties:

```
app.redis.ttl=100
```

and it will be awesome to have an opportunity to change it on property level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure settings by creating a subclass of `KeyspaceConfiguration` and configuring `@EnableRedisRepositories`. There's no property-based configuration for global TTL.

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = MyKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
public class MyConfig {

}

public class MyKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {


    @Override
    public boolean hasSettingsFor(Class<?> type) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyspaceSettings getKeyspaceSettings(Class<?> type) {

        KeyspaceSettings keyspaceSettings = new KeyspaceSettings(type, "my-keyspace");
        keyspaceSettings.setTimeToLive(3600L);

        return keyspaceSettings;
    }
}
```

Deriving from `KeyspaceConfiguration` is intended to provide `Iterable<KeyspaceSettings> initialConfiguration()` in the first place but since you want to apply that settings to all classes, the  in-place creation of `KeyspaceSettings` makes more sense.

You also might want to cache the `KeyspaceSettings` to not create instances all over so Java 8's `Map.computeIfAbsent(…)` would be a good fit.

Comment: thank you, I've read about KeyspaceSettings, but I didn't know about hasSettingsFor method, I thought I had to create new KeyspaceSettings for each entity.

Comment: And I think Spring devs should provide simpler solution, just to add a flag to avoid this configuration, cause it looks too verbose.