# SpringBoot Redis time to live does not work

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to set the life of an object in Redis cache so that it will be evicted. After a set time in this case 60 seconds. If I understand how it works then the following code snippet should work.

.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(60) This will remove the entry after 60 seconds from the redis cache.

This is the config

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializationContext;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.RedisSerializer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.opsec.shared.harvesting.fetcher")
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.throttling.repository")
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

       @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

       @Bean
       public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
           RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
           redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
           return redisTemplate;
       }

       @Bean
       public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
           RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                   .disableCachingNullValues()
                   .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(60)
                   .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.json()));
           redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();
          return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory)
                           .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
       }
}
```

This is the entity

```
@RedisHash("rate")
public class Rate implements Serializable  {
       @Id
       private String url;
       private Integer rate = 0;

       public Rate(String url, Integer rate) {
             super();
             this.url = url;
             this.rate = rate;
       }

       public Integer getRate() {
             return rate;
       }

       public void setRate(Integer rate) {
             this.rate = this.rate+rate;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
             return "Rate [rate=" + rate + "]";
       }
}
``
This is the yml file`
```

server.port: 8080
spring:
cache:
type: redis
redis:
host: localhost
port: 6379

Comment: You are configuring the cache manager used by the `@Cacheable` annotation. You instead need to configure the [Spring Data Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations) annotations `@RedisHash(timeToLive=...)` or `@TimeToLive`.

Comment: Thank you. @RedisHash(value="Rate", timeToLive = 60) Does work.
The only reason I was trying not to use it was I was trying to make timeToLive configurable from my applications.yml. But timeToLive requires a Long. Buy better to have hardcoded that works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data Redis global TTL for all entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577222/spring-data-redis-global-ttl-for-all-entities)

Comment: Yes it does, I  cant find the accept this as an  answer link